# Sony Vegas: Will re-rendering a video with identical video encoding reduce quality?

Tags: mp4, h.264, sony-vegas

I have edited and exported a video in Sony Vegas Pro 13 using the preset 1920x1080-30p video template (mp4, AVC, 16 Mbps). However, I need to reedit the audio of the video, and would like to know if this will affect the video quality.

- If I import the video and edit the audio-track only and then export it with "identical video encoding", is Vegas (or any other popular video editing tool, such as Adobe Premiere) smart enough to not re-compress the video?
- If yes on my first question, will cutting the video reduce quality even if the rearranged video segments are intact otherwise?

Comment: I cannot comment on Sony Vegas, but there are tools out there that will allow you to remux audio without touching the video :)

Comment: popular pro editing programs do have methods where the video is not re-encoded. Sometimes it can be hard to tell, the rapid speed which it wites the new file out though is one clue. You can also cut usually also and have no re-encoding occuring. some key things are to make sure your project settings, the input files and the output settings all match. Some of them even have a "settings viewer" for that purpose.  ANY filtering, adjusting, transitions added will definatly be re-coded. It can also be very important what codec is being used, the program just might not support that for some codec.